# by MISTICALLY DELETED /FORMATTED MY SAM SUNG GTI8262 MY OS

Tags: custom-roms

I am using a *Samsung Galaxy GTi8262* mobile. I'm trying to update it from 4.1.2 to 5.0 manually via Odin 3.

I entered ClockworkMod recovery mode and installed Lolipop ROM 5.0 (provided by vaibhav and rempz company), and it installed successfully. My device works well except for one thing: when I start my phone there's a yellow triangle on screen (and the brand/model of my mobile), and cant go further.

I try to fix this problem by removing the battery, but it does not work. So finally again I entered CWM by pressing <kbd>power</kbd> + <kbd>home</kbd> + <kbd>vol up</kbd> buttons, and by mistake I deleted/formatted my System. Now my mobile only shows "Samsung" on screen.

Please help me: How can I solve this issue and get my device working again?

Comment: Shivam, you were not meant to simply copy/paste your deleted post but also apply some formatting. It's really hard to read – which explains the down-votes.

Comment: There's no official update past 4.1.2 for said device, as listed on [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-I8262/). You've most definitely flashed something not for your device, which in turn caused the yellow triangle. Where did you find the update file you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Flash a stock firmware, everything should be fine. Head [here](http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=GT-I8262) and download the firmware for your country/region